# Are there Magic: The Gathering lore books for the recent blocks?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm trying to find information on the lore of the recent blocks, namely Battle for Zendikar, Shadows over Innistrad, and Kaladesh.  It looks like all the previous sets up through Theros had an accompanying 2-3 book series.

Are there book series' for the recent sets?

Comment: It appears there are no physical books for these blocks (yet?)
http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Books  
But, you can find quite a lot about lore at the magicthegathering.com site in the "Story" section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wizards of the Coast stopped printing physical novels with the Return to Ravnica block [due to them not selling particularly well](http://dougbeyermtg.tumblr.com/post/99331420759/ebooks-and-the-accessibility-of-magics-story). Starting with Battle for Zendikar they started a series of books that showcase the art from the current plane and give an overview of the story from that plane, these books are titled *The Art of Magic: the Gathering - [Plane Name]*.

During Return to Ravinica block they still had novels, but they were only released in ebook form. After Theros they moved all of the story for Magic to the [Magic Story](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/columns/magic-story-archive) (previously called Uncharted Realms) column on their website. Periodically they compile several stories into an ebook format and release that (they usually do this every block or so), for example the [Magic Origins and Prologue to Battle for Zendikar](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/magic-fiction-ebook-collection-2015-09-23).